# uwsgi emperor mod not working

Tags: python, virtualenv, uwsgi

when i start it without emperor it works:

```
uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/vassals/uwsgi.conf --uid books --gid books
```

But when i use emperor mode it freezes:

```
uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals  --uid books --gid books
```

And give such response:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.1 (64bit) on [Fri Oct 24 10:47:46 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) on 24 October 2014 10:36:47
os: Linux-3.10.0-123.8.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 22 19:06:58 UTC 2014
nodename: essenly.com
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi
setgid() to 1000
setuid() to 1000
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 3839
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
*** starting uWSGI Emperor ***
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: .conf is not a valid vassal extension. Use .ini, .xml .js or whatever your monitor supports

Comment: thanks man, i think i must work less)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE. Ignore my advice regarding `master`. Doc says that emperor mode should not be used with `master` normally. http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Emperor.html#notes

Try to run emperor with master process. Add `master = true` to your ini file and run uwsgi as root. Workers will downgrade to non-priviledged user (if specified)

Comment: there was a stupid mistake) i save vassal config with sufix .conf instead .ini ))